# Is there any purpose of declaring lambda followed by immediately invocation to initialize local variable using its return value?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

```
template<typename T>
    static const Metatype* get_metatype() {
        static const Metatype* mt = []() {
            constexpr size_t name_hash = Metatype::build_hash<T>().name_hash;

            auto type = metatype_cache.find(name_hash);
            if (type == metatype_cache.end()) {
                constexpr Metatype newtype = Metatype::build<T>();
                metatype_cache[name_hash] = newtype;
            }
            return &metatype_cache[name_hash];
        }();
        return mt;
    }
```

Variable *mt* initialized by lambda's return value. Why not just extract lambda code and make it part of get_metatype() function then just return value from it?  Is this some performance trick or what??

This code from decs https://github.com/vblanco20-1/decs project that i am learning for educational purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `mt` is declared `static`, meaning that there is only one instance (with static storage duration) of `mt` for each `T` in the program or in each translation unit (depending on whether the function shown is a `static` function in a class or at namespace scope) and if the function `get_metatype<T>()` is called multiple times in the program, only the first call reaching `mt`'s declaration will execute `mt`'s initializer and initialize `mt`. The other calls will simply return the then-fixed value of `mt`. This is even guaranteed to hold when multiple threads are involved, without the initializer ever being called in two of the threads.

Using a directly-invoked lambda in the initializer allows one to put all the code that should be executed only once to initialize the variable `mt` in one place inline without having to create a new function for it. If you put the statements inside the lambda directly in the body of `get_metatype<T>()`, then they would be executed *each* time the function is called and not only once, and the responsibility of avoiding data races in the initialization when multiple threads are involved would shift to you.

In particular, possible reasons for using the `static` `mt` here might be that there are multiple threads and a data race on the construction of the the "metatype" must be avoided, although there would still seem to be a race condition or even a data race on `metatype_cache` if multiple calls to `get_metatype<T>()` for different `T` are made, because the `find` and the placement into the container are not done atomically.

Or a possible reason could be that the lookup operations into `get_metatype` take too long to execute each time `get_metatype` is called, although a `static` variable is not the best choice for performance optimization either, since it requires thread-safe checks on each call to verify whether `mt` has already been initialized.

Answer (score 1):

This is commonly used to initialize a variable that needs to be `const`, but is also complex to initialize. e.g.

```
const std::vector<int> v = [] {
   std::vector<int> vv;
   // ... very complicated logic to initialize vv
   // even could be IO, etc ...
   return vv;
}();
```

without doing this, there's no good way to make `v` `const`.

However, in your case, the reason for using this technique in the provided example, is so that the static variable `mt` is not initalized on every call to `get_metatype`, as pointed out by @walnut, and @Remylebeau.

Comment: @cigien no, `mt` itself is a **non-const** pointer to a `const Metatype` object, it is not a **const** pointer to an object.

Comment: I edited the answer to add the static initialization reason. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @cigien said - a static variable is initialized only once.  C++11 and later ensure that initialization is performed in a thread-safe manner.  Using a lambda for the initializer ensures that the lambda is called only once.  If you were to inline the lambda's code directly in `get_metatype()`, you would be responsible for manually serializing the code yourself, such as with a mutex.