# Assigning a function to, or doing operations in, a variable in C++

Tags: c++

I just saw something really weird on a Leetcode problem and I can't find anything by searching for it online so I'm gonna try here.

Has anyone ever seen a function being assigned to a variable like so:

```cpp
int init = [] {

    // ... Some code here ...
    // ... Dealing with i/o ...

    exit(0);
    return 0;
}();
```

What is this called? Is `init` going to end up as an empty array or an array with one element `[0]` when it returns?
If anyone can share any insight, I'd really appreciate it whole lot.

I found this from one of the top solutions to this problem on Leetcode:
https://leetcode.com/problems/majority-element/description/

As a side note:
I'm assuming that the brackets `{}` in this case are for a function, since I don't know what else to call this? I've never seen it used with a variable like in this case, where without code it just looks like

```cpp
int init = [] {}();
```

Comment: It's a lambda that is immediatly invoked, and the result assigned to `init`. See here: [Is there any purpose of declaring lambda followed by immediately invocation to initialize local variable using its return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61109814/is-there-any-purpose-of-declaring-lambda-followed-by-immediately-invocation-to-i).

Comment: See [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Comment: It's called a lambda function. I guess this is what happens when you learn by doing, instead of learning by studying. Both are good of course, but to learn C++ effectively you really need to [get a book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/) and start studying as well as doing some coding.

Comment: I see such questions about lambdas coming up periodically. The usual reflex might have been "Google it on your own" but to be fair: How do you google something which consists of different kinds of braces only? ;-) ([google "int init = [\] {}();"](https://www.google.com/search?q=int+init+%3D+%5B%5D+%7B%7D()%3B))

Comment: leetcode is really bad at teaching you anything useful, you can read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and here for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @Scheff'sCat `[]<class=void>(){}();` we are just a tiny step away from `[]<>(){}();` being valid c++ :D

Comment: @wohlstad A Lambda expression! Of Course! I completely forgot those existed since I never had to use one. Thank you!

Comment: @Scheff'sCat EXACTLY! I tried googling this for about an hour before I gave up and came here. Before this, I'd never seen so many back-to-back brackets in one spot in C++. Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this:

```cpp
//              lambda function 
//         VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
int init = [] { /*...*/ return 0; }();
//                                 ^^
//                        immediately invoked
```

it is like doing the below separate lambda function definition and call:

```cpp
auto lambda = [] { /*...*/ return 0; };

int init = lambda();  // here we call lambda
```

`init` is not array type as we should declare array like this:

```cpp
int init[] ={1,2,3}; // or
int init[2] = {1,2};
```

NOTE: `[]` is just at the right of `init`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely forgot about lambda's in C++. I learned about them back in Uni but never had a chance to use them. I'm bookmarking this to my C++ Knowledge folder, Thank You!